# Saying that I’m a good self-learner and that I have a high self-discipline in resume

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I’m trying to translate my resume to English and English is not my native language. 
In the section where I described myself I want to say that I’m a good self-learner and that I have “high” self-discipline, but I don’t know how to put it.
First of all, should I write self-learner? self-taught? Autodidact?
Also, I wrote “An excellent self-learner with high self-discipline”, but something there doesn’t seems right to me.
How should I put this line into my resume?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

:I would avoid using the word **self** too many times.  it is repetitive and also somewhat redundant because you are describing yourself.

What you say on a resume and how you say it depends on the job you are applying for. 
You could try the following:

**I'm  highly motivated, disciplined and a fast learner.**  I think this covers everything that you wanted to say.

Try finding a website that provides list of **verbs, adverbs and adjectives** that are useful for resumes or CVs  Many of these sites exist and are often categorized according to the type of job you are applying for.